# How do I access to GCP vm from external if I set up later?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-20.04

Environment:
Google Cloud Platform
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I've created below environment on GCP.

1. I've created: network `nw1` (for ssh from external), `nw2` (private), `nw3` (public)
2. I've created `vm1` (nic with `nw1`, `nw2`, `ExternalIP` in `nw1`)
3. I can access `vm2` using `ExternalIP` from external my machine
4. I've created `vm2` (nic with `nw2`, `nw3` without `ExternalIP`)
5. I can access `vm2` via ssh to `vm1` and then ssh via `nw2`
6. I've created new `ExternalIP` to `nw3` and set `vm2`
7. Now I cannot access (icmp, ssh, etc.) `vm2` via `nw3` (Firewall allows all traffic form `0.0.0.0/0`)

What should I change?

Comment: Please double-check the description. You cay you can access vm2 using external IP, but said it's in private nw2. Where is vm3 located?

Comment: sorry, in 7. , vm3 is incorrect, that is vm2.(fixed)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand your setup, however, in order to allow communication between subnetworks, firewall rules must permit two-way communication.
So for example:
Firewall in NW2 must allow packets from NW3
AND
Firewall in NW3 must allow packets from NW2

It can be helpful to enable [Firewall logging](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewall-rules-logging) and trace the packets to find where they are being dropped.